# Does Golang Yaml Unmarshal Support accessing nested yaml through struct tags?

Tags: go, yaml

I have a simple yaml file with nested values, e.g.

```
name: pamela
favourites: 
  book: the-lion-the-witch-and-the-wardrobe
  movie: barbie
```

I can successfully unmarshal that using the `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` library into the following struct:

```
type Person struct {
  Name string `yaml:"name"`
  Favourites *Favourites `yaml:"favourites"`
}

type Favourites struct {
  Book string `yaml:"book"`
  Movie string `yaml:"movie"`
}
```

Is there a way to flatten the yaml where I don't want to create the struct `favourites` but write the values of favourite book and movie to top level attributes.

So for example, the below does not work but is there anything like it that would allow me to read nested yaml values like this?

```
type Person struct {
  Name string `yaml:"name"`
  FavouriteBook `yaml:"favourites.book"`
  FavouriteMovie `yaml:"favourites.movie"`
}
```

Caveat: I've seen the option of implementing a custom unmarshaller. I'd like to avoid that, so my question is more - does anyone know a yaml library that already supports this?

Comment: I think the best way to solve this is to define a second type representing what-you-want (with the flat set of fields) and map unmarshaled `Person`'s into instances of it. The Go type (e.g. `Person`) correctly represents the structure of the YAML so you retain the ability to (un)marshal to YAML **and** you get the ability to transform the types into the structure that you want.

Comment: See: https://go.dev/play/p/iwA34Uv_grs

Comment: That's what I have done alright, but I'm not going to need to marshal it out into yaml again, so I was hoping for a way to cut out the middle man and just marshal directly to the desired end struct.

Answer (score 0):

With native Golang Unmarshal I don't believe you can do it without a custom Unmarshaller. That said, [gson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) seems to offer that feature.